# Files don't load outside of editor

Tags: java

What should I do to get a path to an image that is located within my project, so that it works while programming, and after I build it? The files are ones that I will have compiled into my project.

I tried this:

```
public String getProjectLocation(){
    File directory = new File("");
    return directory.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

It is then used like so:

```
public String projectLoc = this.getProjectLocation();
this.setBackground(projectLoc + "/src/media/images/ladscape1.jpg");
```

But once I build the project and run it outside of my editor it doesn't work anymore, it no longer loads the proper images.

Comment: From the looks of things, you are using Eclipse.  The `src` folder won't exist once you've build/exported you project, also the, resources you are trying to access are likely to be contained within the projects Jar file.  You will want to use either `getClass().getResource("/media/images/ladscape1.jpg")` OR if the resources are exported as external resources, drop the `/src` folder from the path

Comment: The `getProjectLocation()` will fail under a variety of circumstances.  Sun (before Oracle bought them) thought it was a risk to expose that information to the app., and have taken steps to limit the availability of the installed location.

Comment: Okay so the getResource works but not with my fonts... `InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(filename); font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, is); font = font.deriveFont(fontSize);` I am getting this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical` but it works within the editor and all my image files.

Comment: Not sure what I did, but I got it working, thanks!